# warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

Tags: c

1. The program snippet was written for prime number extraction.
2. The warning was thrown by the compiler as that like the title.

   ```
   while(count<=n)
   { 
     for(c=2;c=(i-1);c++) //the warning is shown here
     { 
        if(i%c==0) 
          break; 
     }     
     if(c==i) 
     { 
        printf("%d ",i); 
        count++; 
     } 
     i++; 
   }
   ```

thanks to you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle expression of an `if` statement is usually a conditional such as `i < n`. In your case, it is an assignment.

The compiler is warning you that perhaps you made a mistake and you meant to use

```
c == (i-1)
```

instead of

```
c = (i-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `c=(i-1)`, you should have `c==(i-1)`. The former assigns a value, but you just mean to be checking the value there.